# MacOS/OSx - Changing the metadata on an iTunes Library Song/Item Programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, itunes

I'm able to programmatically (Swift) access the array of MLMediaObject-s in the iTunes MLMediaGroup.  But I don't see how I can change the metadata on the songs.  I'm calculating the beatsPerMinute (which is usually zero in iTunes) and I want to write it back to the iTunes library or item.  Does anyone know how I can do that.  The MediaLibrary  docs say "Access read-only collections of the user’s multimedia content," so I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation suggests, the MediaLibrary framework only provides read-only access to the user's media collection. It cannot be used to modify items in the library -- not even their metadata.

If you want to modify metadata, you need to go about it some other way. The only method I'm aware of would be to use AppleScript to retrieve and modify the appropriate item, e.g.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set bpm of current track to 130
end tell
```